How is the air in my duct increasing in temperature so fast?
Tl;dr version: The air temp is increasing inside a structurally sound and well connected flex duct by 5 to 10 deg f within 8 feet of the air handler. There is no observable external heat source.  How is this possible?  Me and my HVAC contractor are stumped.
More details:
I have a weird problem that neither I nor my HVAC guy can explain.  I have an air handler that splits into two branches.  Branch 1 is about 55 deg at the vents. Branch 2 is about 65 deg at the vents. These are surface temps I took with my infrared.  My HVAC used a proper air temp probe, and his results were consistent though at slightly different temps. Airspeed and cfm coming out of all vents is good and consistent in both branches... 14 f/s at the best about about 8 f/s at the worst.
We started at the air handler and confirmed that the air coming pushing into each branch is (obviously) the same temp at about 51 deg. On both sides/branches.
Branch 1 is fine at the vent at 55 deg at the vent so we left that alone in our inspection.
For branch 2, after about 8 feet into the duct where it goes into the wall, we cut a hole in the Flex-duct and measured air temp; it had already increased 5 to 10 degrees.    Somehow, in the flex duct, it is taking on that much heat with no explanation.  We confirmed no leaks in the duct, we resealed it to the air handler, there's no other joint between the handler and where we cut and checked.  My tankless water heater and a couple hot water lines are nearby, but we confirmed no hot lines were touching the duct and there was no damage to the duct insulation or foil wrap.  The duct is in an enclosed interior basement-type space that has reasonable ambient temperature.
We cannot figure out how the air temp is increasing 5 to 10 deg over about 8 feet inside a properly sealed and structurally sound flex duct.
Any ideas?

Did you verify that the insulation in the flex duct is there/intact?

A hidden hole/leak would be my guess, sucking in warmer air.  Most other guesses would probably start to go in the weird file.  An inspection camera inside the duct might help.

Does the duct run against an exterior wall?

Yes we verified the duct was essentially like new.   Checked for leaks.  Duct does not run against an exterior wall in the 8 feet span that we cut into and checked. And does not appear to run along any uninsulated walls for the rest of the span either.
